# WSO2 Identity Server wrong redirect-callback host but right path

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, wso2-identity-server

i try to run wso2 idenitity on IIS server, all work normally but when i try it on server i get wrong signin-callback.

The following is a picture of the callback-uri that I registered with the service provider
[registered callback uri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyNaK.png) like this `regexp=(http://localhost:4003/api/oauth2/v2/signin-callback)`

what I get next when I try to login using the service provider:
[callback url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gct2U.png) like this `https://host/api/oauth2/v2/signin-callback?code=d3d16661-0312-3be1-bebb-5940dd267000&session_state=1331111359c3f5029f733f196037241203bc22c164f7910572d38647c4269a16.6KtgBQ2Z7AIOjVALA6UYdQ`

authorize payload when logging in:
[payload redirect uri when authorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgFIh.png)

Comment: Please check below conditions 1 and 2 satisfied. (1). You need to allow multiple callback URLs your application is reachable e.g. https://isuruuy.medium.com/use-regex-in-callback-url-on-api-manager-store-370debeb9f8c   (2). You need to send the callback_uri on the authorisation call https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

Comment: I found the root of the problem. when i use reverse proxy on iis and add web.config config, there will be problem where redirect-callback will be redirected to host.

when I don't use revese proxy everything works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the properties file of your service provider and change the value of callBackUrl property to `http://localhost:4003/api/oauth2/v2/signin-callback`. For example if its pickup-dispatch app[1] hosted in tomcat, you can find the properties file in <TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/pickup-dispatch/WEB-INF/classes/dispatch.properties file.

If this doesn't solve your issue, please provide any error logs printed and the SP properties file for further analysis.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/login/sso-for-oidc/#pickup-dispatch_1

Comment: I found the root of the problem. when i use reverse proxy on iis and add web.config config, there will be problem where redirect-callback will be redirected to host.

when I don't use revese proxy everything works normally.